# Creating a Custom Formatter to replace a Link with an Icon / Image

Tags: views, entities

I would like to replace links in a view I have created with icons. The links are dynamic(varying URLS) but will be be within 5 domains, eg:
www.example.com/page7
www.example.com/page2
www.example2.com/page9
www.example3.com/page77

I would like to provide an Icon for each of the Domains which is applied to the link, so that clicking on the link takes the user to the URL(in a new window) and the text is hidden.
I am aware of CSS image replacement technique but would like to use https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters to do this. I am also aware of https://drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter .

Using the Custom Links Formatter module would allow me to import/export, save, reuse and share this function.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the **rewrite results option in the view** for the field you want the changes then just add the following :

```
 <a>href ="www.example.com/page7 "><img src="sites/all/...your image 
    path"></a>
```

In a similar way you can add images

Comment: Thank you Harshal. While this will work I will have to rewrite results each and every time I want to do this. I am hoping to create a set-up so that it does it automatically when certain conditions are met. ( I tried to mark answer useful but do have the rep, sorry)

Comment: @harshal Is there any way to create a url formatter filter so that it can be used in a text format (plain text or filtered html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this module will help you on that http://customformatters.com/